# String(90) "{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2020-02-04T04:17:16Z", "hostname": "localhost" }" error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, login

Tengo un inicio de sessión que incluye email, password y verificación de captcha y todo esto lo hago de forma local, pero en cuanto ingreso algún dato mal me aparece este mensaje:

```
  String(90) "{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2020-02-04T04:17:16Z", "hostname": "localhost" }" error
```

**¿Qué significa?**

Este es mi código:

```
 <?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$secret = '**********************************************';
if(!$captcha){
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Por favor verifica el captcha.");
window.location.href="../login.php";
</script>';
}
$response = 
file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? 
secret=$secret&response=$captcha");
var_dump($response);
$arr = json_decode($response, TRUE);
if($arr['success']){

$query = "SELECT nombre_empresa, categoria, rango_empleados, pin, activo FROM 
empresasregistradas where email = '$email' and password = '$password' and 
rango_empleados='Menos de 50' and activo='Si'";



 $bdconect = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);
 $parametros = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($bdconect) > 0){
 $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
 $_SESSION['name'] = $parametros['nombre_empresa'];
 $_SESSION['cate'] = $parametros['categoria'];
 $_SESSION['rang'] = $parametros['rango_empleados'];
 $_SESSION['pin'] = $parametros['pin'];
  header("location: ../panel.php");
}else{
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrectos");
window.location.href="../login.php";
</script>';
}
}else{
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Error al verificar el captcha.");
window.location.href="../login.php";
</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Esa parece ser la salida que provoca esta línea de tu código: `var_dump($response);` Y no parece que haya error realmente, pues el objeto tiene una clave  `success` con valor `true`, lo cual quiere decir que el resultado fue exitoso.

Comment: @A. Cedano Gracias¡

Comment: @A. Cedano ¿Cómo puedo hacer que no salga esa notificación? Solo quito el var_dump($response);?

Comment: Sí, los `var_dump` se suelen usar en fase de depuración, para verificar el estado de las variables, pero cuando el código funciona hay que quitarlos. Aunque, no sé por qué motivo a tu salida se le está agregando la palabra `error` que quizá proviene de otro sitio. El `var_dump` está arrojando una cadena de `90`, entre las `{}` hay `84`caracteres, así que el resto no sé de dónde viene.

Comment: Quizá si abres en el navegador la url de `file_get_contents` podrás verificar si esa palabra `error` aparece o no.

Comment: Gracias, experimente y funcionó @A.Cedano, dios te bendiga

Comment: Me alegro de que haya funcionado. Bendiciones también para ti. Saludos.